# UITableCell content corruption when scrolling

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

I've got a UITableView with a cell that has a UIWebView in it and I've got 2 problems with the table. First the web view covers the cell it is in so it makes the cell look a little weird.

The second more severe problem and the main question for this thread is the corruption that happens when I scroll the table. Randomly the web view will be rendered in the wrong cell and the faster I scroll the more cells get corrupted like this. If I scroll slowly everything renders like it should.

when the table is initially drawn it is rendered correctly. It only starts to go bad when the user scrolls the table. When it messes up a UIWebView is appearing on some of the cells it shouldn't be. This happens unless you scroll slowly and the faster you scroll the worse it is. This isn't just a graphical glitch either as there is an active live web view in these cells where there shouldn't be. I also noticed that my cell accessory icon is getting changed on the first cell from none to disclosure triangle as well. I tried posting some images of this but I'm too new to be allowed (spammers ruining the fun for everyone)

Here's my code for cellForRowAtIndexPath. Please be gentle I am just learning how all this works. :)

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifierMediaType];
    switch ([indexPath section]) {
        case 0: {
            if (!cell) {
                cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifierLongDescription];
            }
            [cell.contentView addSubview:self.longDescriptionWebView];
            break;
        }
        case 1: {
            if (!cell) {
                cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifierMediaType];
            }
            NSDictionary *cellDict = [self.subMediaTypes objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
            cell.textLabel.text = [cellDict objectForKey:@"SHORT_DESCRIPTION"];
            break;
        }    
        default:
            if (!cell) {
                cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifierMediaType];
            }
            break;
    }

    return cell;
}
```

First I tried to define the reuse cells in cellForRowAtIndexPath but that was yielding the same result so I moved the cells out and set them up as instance variables. This also works but I still have the corruption problem so I am guessing where I was setting up the reuse cells really didn't matter. Here's the block of code where I setup the reuse cells.

```
if (!self.mediaTypeCell) self.mediaTypeCell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifierMediaType];
if (!self.longDescriptionCell) self.longDescriptionCell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifierLongDescription];
if (!self.longDescriptionWebView) self.longDescriptionWebView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.longDescriptionCell.bounds];
self.mediaTypeCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
self.longDescriptionCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
[self.longDescriptionCell.contentView addSubview:self.longDescriptionWebView];
self.longDescriptionCell.contentView.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
self.longDescriptionWebView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
[self.longDescriptionWebView loadHTMLString:self.mediaTypeLongDescription baseURL:nil];
```

The table only needs two types of cells. There is a single cell with no accessory that contains the web view (longDescriptionCell) and the rest of the table contains cells that hold simple text strings (mediaTypeCell) with the disclosure indicator accessory.

Comment: I think I figured this out! I am using the same instance variable for both types of cells thinking that the variable is new each time through the method but it isn't! I separated each cell type into it's own variable and now I no longer have the UIWebView appearing in odd places.

Answer (score 0):

so... where should we start...?

in general, it's not a good idea to use uiwebview (which are uiscrollview) inside a cell.
but it's not impossible, you have just to care about it, so, if you are just trying to learn how to use tables, you may start with something easier...

by the way, the bigger mistake you are doing:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
// (..)
       if (!cell) {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifierLongDescription];
        }
        [cell.contentView addSubview:self.longDescriptionWebView];
// (..)
}
```

this protocol method is used and called every time your table need to show a cell, so it runs when it is shown the first time (for every cell) and when user scrolls down and up.

the magic of tables is to reuse cells that are going up outside of screen (if user scrolls down) to reuse that same cell down the the new data needed for the down data.

that's way you should ask something like this:

```
   UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifierMediaType];
```

that code just ask if there is an unused cell that we can use for the new needed data.
at this point, if it doesn't exist we need to allocate a new one and set it's objects to show the right data.

BUT if it exists we DON'T need to allocate a new one (and that's what you are doing, ok)
AND we should add new objects in it (or if we do we should remove the old ones in it)

you are adding a web view everytime you scroll, adding it over the old one, with this:

```
       [cell.contentView addSubview:self.longDescriptionWebView];
```

that's the big error, you should just reuse the old webView telling it to load a new html page (or what else you are showing in it)

one more thing: when you use

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifierMediaType];
```

you ask for an existing cell with id CellIdentifierMediaType

but then you ask and use also different id cells (CellIdentifierLongDescription)